# Select an element by particular pattern with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a bunch of elements that contain `data-testid` attributes.

Think of them as something like this:

```js
<div data-testid="my-page">
  <div data-testid="my-page-content"></div>
  <div data-testid="my-page-footer">
    <button data-testid="my-page-action-button">Do something</button>
    <button data-testid="my-page-cancel-button">Cancel</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

For one of my tests, I need to find the buttons through their data test id pattern.

As you can see, it is `my-page-**-button`.

I need to know how to adjust my selectors accordingly so that I grab the elements that begin with `my-page` and end with `button`.

So far, I've been doing:

```js
$("[data-testid^='my-page-']")
```

Unfortunately, this will grab `my-page-content` (or `my-page-footer`). How can I grab all elements with data-testids like `my-page-**-button`?

Comment: Seems like a better naming scheme would make that easier. ;)

Comment: Simple enough if you also include the button tag in selector

Answer (score 4, accepted):

either include the button

```
button[data-testid^='my-page-']
```

or include the ends with

```
[data-testid^='my-page-'][data-testid$='button']
```

```js
console.log($("button[data-testid^='my-page-']").length);

console.log($("[data-testid^='my-page-'][data-testid$='button']").length);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-testid="my-page">
  <div data-testid="my-page-content"></div>
  <div data-testid="my-page-footer">
    <button data-testid="my-page-action-button">Do something</button>
    <button data-testid="my-page-cancel-button">Cancel</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Select with **prefix** AND **Suffix** .

```
$("[data-testid^='my-page-'][data-testid$='-button']")
```

##### RULE in general

- **Execulsive AND** : do not keep space between selector(s)
- **Accumulative AND**: put `,` between selector(s)

You need here the **Execulsive AND**

Answer (score 1):

I think this does what you need:

```
$('[data-testid^=my-page-][data-testid $=button')
```

A working demo is below, let me know if you needed something else.

---

**DEMO**

```js
// Select using start and end selectors
$('[data-testid^=my-page-][data-testid $=button').each( function() {
  console.log($(this).attr("data-testid"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-testid="my-page">
  <div data-testid="my-page-content"></div>
  <div data-testid="my-page-footer">
    <button data-testid="my-page-action-button">Do something</button>
    <button data-testid="my-page-cancel-button">Cancel</button>
  </div>
</div>
```